# Netlogo sublist command

Tags: netlogo

I noticed this instruction

```
set first-tens sublist mylist 0 10
```

causes an error if there are less than 10 elements in `mylist`.

How can I safely get the first 10 elements (or all the presents in `mylist` if there are less than 10)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ifelse-value`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse-value) to do this, combined with just checking the length:

```
set first-tens ifelse-value (length mylist < 10) [ mylist ] [ sublist mylist 0 10 ]
```